# Error when attempting to static_cast<> const char[] to unsigned char *

Tags: c++, arrays, string, casting

I want to cast `const char[]` to `unsigned char *`.

I am using C++ casts (ie:`static_cast`):

```
unsigned char * txt = static_cast<unsigned char *>("AC");
```

When I build the application I get the following error:

> error:invalid static_cast from type 'const char [3]' to type 'unsigned char *'

When I use C like casts:

```
unsigned char * txt = (unsigned char *)"AC";
```

I don't get any compilation error and the program runs perfectly.

I MUST use C++ casts to avoid any runtime errors. How do I cast `const char [3]` to `unsigned char *` using C++ casts?

Comment: Why do you want to cast to non-const ?

Comment: Casting from `const char*` to `char*` even in C is eventually going to lead to Undefined Behavior. Avoid that.

Comment: "I MUST use c++ casts to avoid any runtime errors" - for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unsigned char*` and  `const char[]` are unrelated types, so that `static_cast<>` won't work. And the constness is different, hence a `const_cast<>` is required.

Correct cast:

```
unsigned char* txt = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<char*>("AC"));
```

Please note, that you cannot write through that `unsigned char* txt` pointer, because C++ string literals ("AC" here) are immutable and often stored in read-only memory.

See [`const_cast<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast):

> Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I only use `txt` for comparison so I don't need to modify it. Thanks !

Comment: @LoayAshmawy ..but note, that once you are using `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast` your premise "MUST use c++ casts to avoid any runtime errors" does not hold anymore and concerning safety you could as well use the c-style cast. However, I would still use the c++ casts, because it clearly expresses your intent in the code, it is kind-of a: "I am asking for trouble, but I know what I am doing here"

Comment: @LoayAshmawy If You are going to use it for comparison, there's no need (and no reason) to strip away constness.

Comment: @Bob__ any Idea on how to assign `"AC"` to `txt` that should be an `unsigned char *` or `const unsigned char *`?

Comment: @LoayAshmawy `unsigned char const* txt = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>("AC");`